# How to convert "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm" from one timezone to another?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert "01/14/2019 00:00" to another timezone. But before that, I want to set default timezone as MST to "01/14/2019 00:00". Later, if I convert to PST, it should become "01/13/2019 23:00" because PST is one hour behind MST.

I have tried several examples but none of them are working. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

moment("01/14/2019 00:00", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm").tz("America/Denver").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");

If I do this it is converting to MST. It should not convert to MST, but it should just assume the date time is in MST and convert accordingly. I tried setDefault method as well.

Comment: The `tz` changes the localte, so if you need to convert from one locale to another, _first_ set up your input locale, then input the datetime, _then_ set your output locale, and get your formatted string out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried moment.tz.setDefault(String); with a timezones?

What version not moment are you using?

To use moment-timezone, you will need moment@2.9.0+, moment-timezone.js, and the moment-timezone data.

Comment: I am using moment 2.9.0 and moment-timezone.js. How to set default timezone on specific date time?

Comment: Thanks it's working. But it is setting default globally. How to set only for a particular case?

Answer (score 0):

Try using *moment-timezone* from *npm* : `npm install moment-timezone`

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Check docs for helping https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/